# jQuery DataTable not working in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I've been trying various ways to plug in jQuery DataTables to my mvc app.  After reading http://datatables.net/blog/Microsoft_CDN, I decided that using Microsoft's CDN might be the easiest approach to just get a DataTable up and running.

I copied and pasted the exact code found in the blogs example into Index.vbhtml, but I get "$("#example").dataTable is not a function".  I also tried using the DataTable debugger but it does not find any DataTables on my page.

Because I'm an ASP.net noob and I haven't found any similar problems anywhere, I feel that the problem is something simple that I'm just overlooking.  So I apologize in advance if this is a ridiculous question, but any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you get it working in MVC 3? Find a complete MVC 3 sample. What does $("#example").Text() produce?

Comment: Make sure you are adding jQuery's javascript file to the page before the Datatables javascript file.

Comment: I double checked and the JQuery js file is in fact added before the Datatables.  I'll work on trying it MVC 3 but I thought I would let you know that $("#example").Text() produces the name of the columns followed by the all of the data that is inside the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect a conflict with different versions of jquery.  The version on the CDN and the version of jquery bundled in your MVC site could be conflicting.

Look in your /Views/Shared/_Layout.vbhtml (or _Layout.cshtml for C#) for this line:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

Comment it out and try again, if it works then it was a conflict.

Comment: That means that datatables does not work with MVC4 default jquery version ?