# ASP.NET does not seem to see the .css or .js for DataTables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatables

I'm working on displaying tabular data from a SQL database in a 'aspx' page that I added into an mvc template project I have made inside Visual Studio 2013.

I have a SQL DataSource connected to a database bringing back a basic table.  I can display the information in the 'DataTable.aspx' file.  I am not able to get the dataTables.js or the .css files to run.  Or I do not think that they are running. This is what I have checked so far..

- I can see jquery as having loaded, and I did install both jquery and datatables in the 'NuGet' package manager through Visual Studio 2013 (demo)
- The .net tab in FireFox (sometimes shows that the .js and .cs files in the debug session in black or gray.
  -I think my 'DataTables.aspx' file is correct (below).

  ### <%: Title %>.

  #### TaskTable

  ```
  <div>  
       <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
           ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TaskRFIDatabaseConnectionString %>"
           SelectCommand="SELECT [TaskID], [TaskTypeID], [TaskCreatedBy], [TaskName], [TaskDescription], [TaskCreatedDateTime] FROM [TaskTable]">
       </asp:SqlDataSource>
       <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
           <HeaderTemplate>
               <table id="DataTable">
                  <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th>TaskID</th>
                      <th>TaskTypeID</th>
                      <th>TaskCreatedBy</th>
                      <th>TaskName</th>
                      <th>TaskDescription</th>
                      <th>TaskCreatedDateTime</th>                        
                  </tr>
                  </thead>
           </HeaderTemplate>
           <ItemTemplate>
              <tr>
                  <td><%# Eval("TaskId") %></td>
                  <td><%# Eval("TaskTypeID") %></td>
                  <td><%# Eval("TaskCreatedBy") %></td>
                  <td><%# Eval("TaskName") %></td>
                  <td><%# Eval("TaskDescription") %></td>
                  <td><%# Eval("TaskCreatedDateTime") %></td> 
              </tr>            
           </ItemTemplate>
           <FooterTemplate>
               </table>
           </FooterTemplate>
      </asp:Repeater>          
  </div>
  ```

The site master has the references to the .js and .css files for dataTables.

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="Compass.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %> - Compass</title>
    <link href="Content/DataTables-1.10.3/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/DataTables-1.10.3/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
    <webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />   
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

</head>

<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
            <Scripts>
                <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884 --%>
                <%--Framework Scripts--%>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />

                <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />                  
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />

                <%--Site Scripts--%>
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>

        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/">Application name</a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/About">About</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/DataTable">DataTable</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
                        <AnonymousTemplate>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Register">Register</a></li>
                                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Login">Log in</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </AnonymousTemplate>
                        <LoggedInTemplate>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Manage" title="Manage your account">Hello, <%: Context.User.Identity.GetUserName()  %> !</a></li>
                                <li>
                                    <asp:LoginStatus runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log off" LogoutPageUrl="~/" OnLoggingOut="Unnamed_LoggingOut" />
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </LoggedInTemplate>
                    </asp:LoginView>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container body-content">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeaderContent" runat="server">
                <link href="Content/DataTables-1.10.3/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" />
                <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
                <script src="Scripts/DataTables-1.10.3/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <hr />
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - My ASP.NET Application</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Where else would you check?  All of the examples I have read have been either dealing with a simple page or are using different methods.  This is from a base web/mvc template from Visual Studio 2013 and jQuery dataTables.js installed through NuGet.

Some of the other pages I have already hit:
[jQuery DataTable not working in asp.net mvc 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365344/jquery-datatable-not-working-in-asp-net-mvc-4)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155422/jQuery-DataTables-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Integration-Part

Is there anyplace else I should be looking?
Andy..

Comment: You should seriously consider a better title for your question. Please choose a name that describes the problem you are having. You don't even mention css and javascript at all in there.

Comment: Yep.  Hopefully this will be better

Answer (score 0):

Woo Hoo.. Found it.

I'm learning the ropes in the world of MVC 5 and jQuery/dataTables.

Let me restate the problem:  I had a VS(2013) project (Web / .NetFramework4.5.1 / ASP.NET Web Application / WebForms (checkd 'WebForms', MVC))  I added in the references for jQuery & DataTables through the NuGet Package Manager.  **wrongly thought that this magically put all of the references I needed for the wireup**

I added the following objects via drag drop to the cookie cutter template I used above from Data toolbox:

1. Repeater (source set to the 'SqlDataSource1')
2. SqlDataSource (setup with connection to my database)

So I thought I had all of the jQuery / js / css for using DataTables.  I have done this in straight javascript before (Aptana) and could not figure out where the references for the css would have to be inserted.  I about drove me crazy.

I know, get to it..  The scripts were there but not really doing anything.  A table was generated but didn't have the css or scripty goodness that I wanted.  That was the problem no css or script behavior I expected from dataTables.

What I did:
1.  Started over with a new project, Added jQuery and DataTables through NuGet Package Manager.
2.  Opened up "Site.Master" file and added references to the css in the  section

```
<Link href="Content/DataTables-1.10.3/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

3. Added the reference to the jquery.dataTables.js file in the same file "Site.Master"..

   ```
   <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
       <Scripts>       
           <%--Framework Scripts--%>
           <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
           <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
           <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/DataTables-1.10.3/jquery.dataTables.js" />
           <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
           <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
           <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
           <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
           <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
           <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
           <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
           <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
           <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
           <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
           <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
           <%--Site Scripts--%>
       </Scripts>
   </asp:ScriptManager>
   ```
4. Cleaned / Rebuilt project
5. Added the final script call to the aspx page  (final markup below)

   <%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="maybe._Default" %>
       
           
               
                   
                       
                           
                               StaffID
                               LName
                               FName
                               WorkPhone
                           
                       
               
               
                   
                       <%# Eval("StaffID") %>
                       <%# Eval("LName") %>
                       <%# Eval("FName") %>
                       <%# Eval("WorkPhone") %>
                   
               
               
                   
               
           
       "myselection text">

   $('#DataTable').dataTable();

Rebuilt and then ran it ..  Worked!!. 
Andy

sources:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bfCLyaWHvcM   Sql Repeater
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398991%28v=vs.100%29.aspx